# Docker-Distribution: cannot pull from different machine (FATA[0000] Error: image sample-web-app:latest not found)

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I've installed a private docker repository with the docker distribution registry (not the old docker-registry). I can query the api from another machine and see the my pushed image, but I can't pull it.

On machine A I have installed a docker distribution container:

```
sudo docker run --name=registry --restart=always -d -p 5000:5000 registry:2.0
```

I've created and pushed my image on machine A.

```
$ sudo docker push 192.168.0.14:5000/sample-web-app
The push refers to a repository [192.168.0.14:5000/sample-web-app] (len: 1)
ab8ada80460c: Image already exists 
efe2cfd1b891: Image successfully pushed 
5a1f4c3d95f7: Image successfully pushed 
2f20cd8c82e9: Image successfully pushed 
6996ab83c944: Image successfully pushed 
f11858d1ad30: Image successfully pushed 
77820c2410c3: Image already exists 
8f4c453a5ccf: Image successfully pushed 
78214790fb9d: Image already exists 
5ab0027638b0: Image already exists 
78e0f5c7f8cc: Image successfully pushed 
75631aa15af4: Image successfully pushed 
8d2d7c43813c: Image successfully pushed 
389061f16e00: Image successfully pushed 
66e6b2b8450d: Image successfully pushed 
22ffb090109d: Image successfully pushed 
41f8e45936c6: Image successfully pushed 
fd15f8f632ed: Image successfully pushed 
e7e61dab0443: Image successfully pushed 
facfdaf41727: Image already exists 
07f8e8c5e660: Image already exists 
37bea4ee0c81: Image successfully pushed 
a82efea989f9: Image successfully pushed 
e9e06b06e14c: Image successfully pushed 
Digest: sha256:bcb172fe60efa418b8f0240346314a43a74f841882653a30e372c2d59a84dfe6
```

Then I deleted the local image on machine A.

```
$sudo docker rmi 192.168.0.14:5000/sample-web-app
Untagged: 192.168.0.14:5000/sample-web-app:latest
Deleted: ab8ada80460c055c637b77691f1dbe67e6377c29dfd06c820596f0247dd401f1
Deleted: efe2cfd1b891d94ab99b82c0d661b3af9d22a216379de596836bb365b618653a
Deleted: 5a1f4c3d95f72c3b50bd2e3df477cdb6e3e1793d8b96199572fba075a197a642
```

I pulled the image successfully on machine A.

```
$ sudo docker pull 192.168.0.14:5000/sample-web-app
latest: Pulling from 192.168.0.14:5000/sample-web-app
5a1f4c3d95f7: Pull complete 
efe2cfd1b891: Pull complete 
ab8ada80460c: Already exists 
e9e06b06e14c: Already exists 
a82efea989f9: Already exists 
37bea4ee0c81: Already exists 
07f8e8c5e660: Already exists 
facfdaf41727: Already exists 
e7e61dab0443: Already exists 
fd15f8f632ed: Already exists 
41f8e45936c6: Already exists 
22ffb090109d: Already exists 
66e6b2b8450d: Already exists 
389061f16e00: Already exists 
8d2d7c43813c: Already exists 
75631aa15af4: Already exists 
78e0f5c7f8cc: Already exists 
5ab0027638b0: Already exists 
78214790fb9d: Already exists 
8f4c453a5ccf: Already exists 
77820c2410c3: Already exists 
f11858d1ad30: Already exists 
6996ab83c944: Already exists 
2f20cd8c82e9: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:bcb172fe60efa418b8f0240346314a43a74f841882653a30e372c2d59a84dfe6
Status: Downloaded newer image for 192.168.0.14:5000/sample-web-app:latest
```

I can reach the registry running on a container on machine A from machine B, but I cannot pull from it.

```
$ curl http://192.168.0.14:5000/v2/sample-web-app/tags/list
{"name":"sample-web-app","tags":["latest"]}
$ docker pull 192.168.0.14:5000/sample-web-app
Pulling repository 192.168.0.14:5000/sample-web-app
FATA[0000] Error: image sample-web-app:latest not found

$ docker version
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): a8a31ef-dirty
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): a8a31ef-dirty
```

Comment: Try with a newer version of Docker (1.6 not 1.5).

Comment: This is not an option to me because machine B is running the stable channel of coreos. Using beta or alpha for production is not what I want.

Comment: I think you will have problems with the new version of the registry and versions of Docker older than 1.6. But I don't know if that's the problem here or not.

Comment: Just to clarify; the usage instructions do list 1.6 as a requirement: https://github.com/docker/distribution

Comment: I havn't seen that. Ok, in this case I have to stick to the old registry.